# Mysql Update Self Join , Increment Column value based on Group

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, auto-increment

I have a table whose structure is similar to below .

+----+---------------+-------+
| id |      group    | value |
+----+---------------+-------+
|  1  | g1           |  null |
|  2  | g1            |  null |
|  3  | g2             |  null |
|  4  | g2             |  null |
|  5  | g2             |  null |
|  6  | g3             |  null |
|  7  | g3             |  null |
|  8  | g4               |  null |
|  9  | g4              |  null |
+----+---------------+-------+

I need to update the value column so that the table looks like

+----+---------------+-------+
| id |      group    | value |
+----+---------------+-------+
|  1  | g1           |  1 |
|  2  | g1            |  2 |
|  3  | g2             |  1 |
|  4  | g2             |  2 |
|  5  | g2             |  3 |
|  6  | g3             |  1 |
|  7  | g3             |  2 |
|  8  | g4               |  1 |
|  9  | g4              |  2 |
+----+---------------+-------+

Basically i am increment the `value` column based on the `group` column .

Comment: mysql version please

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to store values calculated from other table contents. (Data redundancy and risk of data inconsistency. Consider the case when the row with id = 4 is deleted, what will happen?) Create a view instead, it will always be up do date!

Comment: Don't create a view. Just calculate the value when you need it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try below - using self join

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=035a814c9533acfe87850ca881140cbb)**

```
update tablename t
join
(select b.id,b.groupname,count(b.id) as val from t1 a
join t1 b on a.groupname=b.groupname
and a.id<=b.id
group by b.id,b.groupname
)d on t.id=d.id
set value=val
```

OR

you can use `row_number()` function if your mysql version is 8.0+

```
update tablename t
join
(
  select *, row_number() over(partition by groupname order by id) as rn from t1 
)d on t.id=d.id
set value=rn
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this I hope this is useful for you

```
Update A 
set value = _val
from @tblName As A
INNER JOIN (
SELECT id,Row_NUMBER() over(partition by [group] order by id) as _val  from  @tblName
)As B ON A.id = B.id
```

Answer (score 0):

In older versions of MySQL, variables are the simplest method:

```
set @rn := 0;
set @grp := '';

update t
    set value = (@rn := if(@grp = t.group, @rn + 1,
                           if(@grp := t.group, 1, 1)
                          )
                )
    order by group, id;
```

In MySQL 8.0, use fa06's second query.